How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(y) (\sinh(y))^2 y^3}{2 + (\sinh(2y))^2} \, dy$

Question

How to evaluate
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh(y)  (\sinh(y))^2  y^3}{2 + (\sinh(2y))^2} \, dy$$

My attempt

Since I had no idea how to progress, I used some trigonometric identities to simplify the integral.
$$\frac{\tanh(y) (\sinh(y))^2 y^3}{2 + (\sinh(2y))^2} = \frac{\frac{\sinh(y)}{\cosh(y)} (\sinh(y))^2 y^3}{2 + 4 \sinh^2(y) + 4 \sinh^4(y)} = \frac{y^3 \sinh^2(y) \sinh(2 y)}{(4 \sinh^4(y) + 4 \sinh^2(y) + 2) (\cosh(2 y) + 1)}$$
Here is what I got
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y^3 \sinh^2(y) \sinh(2 y)}{(4 \sinh^4(y) + 4 \sinh^2(y) + 2) (\cosh(2 y) + 1)} \, dy,$$
This is what I have done. Can someone help me?
Mathematica Output
Out[]=((-I)*(-25064*I+15525*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+21735*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-3105*(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Pi^4-3840*I*(-8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[-(-3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)]^4+180*Pi^3*(2*(8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3-2*Sqrt[2]]+5*(-8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3+2*Sqrt[2]])+60*Pi*(2*(8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3-2*Sqrt[2]]^3+(-8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3+2*Sqrt[2]]^3)+30*Pi^2*(-256*I*(-8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[-(-3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)]^2+I*(2*(8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3-2*Sqrt[2]]^2-13*(-8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3+2*Sqrt[2]]^2))+15*I*(2*(8*I+5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3-2*Sqrt[2]]^4+(8*I-5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]-7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]+(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*Log[3+2*Sqrt[2]]^4+6144*(32*I*PolyLog[4,-I]+32*I*PolyLog[4,I]+(5*Sqrt[6-4*Sqrt[2]]+7*Sqrt[3-2*Sqrt[2]]+(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4)*(-1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)+(7-5*Sqrt[2])*Sqrt[3+2*Sqrt[2]]-(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)*(1+Sqrt[2])*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(3/4))*(PolyLog[4,-(((1+I)*(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4))/Sqrt[2])]+PolyLog[4,((1+I)*(3-2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4))/Sqrt[2]]-PolyLog[4,-((1-I)/(Sqrt[2]*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4)))]-PolyLog[4,(1-I)/(Sqrt[2]*(3+2*Sqrt[2])^(1/4))]))))/491520


$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\tanh(y)  (\sinh(y))^2  y^3}{2 + (\sinh(2y))^2} , dy=2\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tanh(y)  (\sinh(y))^2  y^3}{3 + \cosh(4y)},dy$$
$$ =2\frac {\partial^3}{\partial \alpha^3}\bigg|{\alpha=0}2\int{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\tanh(y)  (\sinh(y))^2  e^{\alpha y}}{\cosh\big(\operatorname{arccosh} (3)\big) + \cosh(4y)},dy$$
To evaluate the last integral use the rectangular contour $-R\to R\to R+\pi i\to -R+\pi i\to-R$, and evaluate residues in four poles: $,y=\pm\frac{\operatorname{arccosh} (3)}4+\frac{\pi i}4;,y=\pm\frac{\operatorname{arccosh} (3)}4+\frac{3\pi i}4$

Why don't you use FullSimplify[%] ?

@ClaudeLeibovici I broke my laptop screen, so I was using Wolfram Cloud on my mobile browser. It was taking too much time, and my phone started overheating and lagging.

Again downvote without any explanations?

Notice that $\cos ^{-1}(3)=i ,\log \left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)$

Let’s keep it real with $a= \sqrt2+1 $ and proceed as follows after Claude’s variable change
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y^3\tanh y \sinh^2y }{2 + \sinh^2 2y}\overset{t=e^{2y}}{dy} \\
=&\ \frac 1 {16} \int_0^\infty\frac{(t-1)^3 \ln^3t}{ (t+1)\left(t^4+6 t^2+1\right)}\,dt\\
 =&\ \frac 1 {16} \int_0^\infty  \ln^3t \bigg[\frac1{4\sqrt2}\bigg(\frac t{\frac 1{a^2}t^2 +1} -\frac t{{a^2}t^2 +1}\bigg) -\frac1{1+t}\bigg]dt\\
 =&\ \frac 1 {16} \frac{d^3}{dp^3}\int_0^\infty  \bigg[\frac1{4\sqrt2}\bigg(\frac {t^{p+1}}{\frac 1{a^2}t^2 +1} -\frac  {t^{p+1}}{{a^2}t^2 +1}\bigg) -\frac {t^{p}}{1+t}\bigg]dt\ \bigg|_{p\to 0^-}\\
 =&\ \frac \pi {16} \frac{d^3}{dp^3}\bigg[\frac1{8\sqrt2}\bigg(\frac1{a^{p+2}}-a^{p+2}\bigg) \csc\frac{\pi p}2+\csc \pi p\bigg]_{p\to 0^-}\\
=&\ \frac{7\pi^4}{1024}- \frac{\pi^2}{128}\ln^2 a-\frac1{64}\ln^4a
\end{align}

Starting from $$ \frac{\tanh(y)  (\sinh(y))^2  y^3}{2 + (\sinh(2y))^2}=\frac{e^{2 y} \left(e^{2 y}-1\right)^3
   y^3}{\left(e^{2 y}+1\right) \left(e^{8 y}+6 e^{4 y}++1\right)}$$
$$e^{2y}=t \quad \implies \quad I=\frac 1 {16} \int \frac{(t-1)^3 \log ^3(t)}{ (t+1)\left(t^4+6 t^2+1\right)}\,dt$$ Write
$$t^4+6 t^2+1=(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)$$ with
$$(a,b)=\pm i \sqrt{3-2 \sqrt{2}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad (c,d)=\pm i \sqrt{3+2 \sqrt{2}}$$ and use partial fraction decomposition to face  five integrals
$$J_k=\int \frac{\log ^3(t)}{t-k}\,dt$$ A few integrations by parts lead to
$$J_k=\log ^3(t) \log\left(1-\frac{t}{k}\right)+3 \log ^2(t)
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)-6 \log (t)
   \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)+6 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)$$
Recombine all of the above, go back to $y$ if you wish and use the bounds. Simplifying the complex numbers
$$I=\frac{1}{2048}\Bigg(14 \pi ^4-\log ^4\left(3-2
   \sqrt{2}\right)+\cos ^{-1}(3)^4+2
   \pi ^2 \left(\cos ^{-1}(3)^2-\log
   ^2\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)\right) \Bigg)$$ which is your nasty result.

Thanks a lot for the answer! Is this the most simplified closed form?
